# Unable to use SQLite in JavaScript based Windows 8 application using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, windows-8.1

I have created a sample Windows 8 JavaScript based application by looking [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html)

However, I am unable to use SQLite database. I have searched various blogs and they all direct towards creating a new project through Cordova console and then add Win8 platform and SQLite plug-in for Windows 8.

Any help would be highly appreciated if I can use the SQLite without using Cordova plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you don't use version 2.2.0 (from your link) as that's quite an old version, and instead switch to the latest version 3.5.0, which is built using the Command Line Tools.

If you're starting a new project use the latest stable version available.

However looking at support for version 3.5.0 you can only get WebSQL (the browser implementation of SQLite) in Android and iOS, for Windows 8 you'll need to use IndexedDB:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Looking back through the documentation for previous versions (2.9.0 pre CLI, 3.1.0) it looks like Windows 7 and 8 never supported WebSQL through Phonegap

There seems to be some plugins that add functionality as you've found, but only for older versions of Cordova (2.7.0 and earlier as far as I can see)

I can think of 3 solutions for you:

- If you're only developing for Windows, try using IndexedDB
- If you're developing across multiple platforms, you can use the `device.platform` feature to detect if you should use `WebSQL` or `IndexedDB` for Android/iOS and Windows
- If your data model is simple enough you could use `LocalStorage` and `JSON` to store strings and simple objects